# Открытие программы через контекстное меню Windows и получение данных в программу

Tags: c#, winforms, реестр, contextmenu

возникла необходимость создать программу упаковщик, которая бы закреплялась в контекстном меню Windows. При нажатии правым щелчком мыши по папке или файлу должно отображаться контекстное меню Windows, среди вариантов программ должно появиться моя программа
[image: там где закрашенная полоса туда я хочу поместить программу]

(там где закрашенная полоса туда я хочу поместить программу)

При нажатии по этой программе путь к той папке или файла, который был выделен на момент появления контекстного меню должен передастся в программу, её я делаю с графическим интерфейсом (WinForm)
У меня вопрос состоит из двух частей:

1. Как программно добавить приложение в контекстное меню
2. Как получать путь к выделенному файлу или папке при загрузке программы таким способом, с графическим интерфейсом (с консольной программой кажется через аргумент функции Main это делается)

Буду рад любой помощи, так как в этой теме я совсем новичок

Comment: Гуглите по ключевым словам `добавить программу в контекстное меню C#`, например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179562/adding-my-program-to-right-click-menu

Comment: Путь к выделенному файлу получается точно так же из аргументов Main. Да, в программе с GUI он тоже есть.

Comment: тут - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer и тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386469/c-sharp-adding-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-all-file-types

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное